# Why my CW was closed?

Tags: discussion

I just [created a community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252360/what-is-the-coolest-stuff-youve-ever-written-closed) some minutes ago, and it got closed as "not a real question". Before writing, I digged up some questions, which were similar in nature, to see if they wouldn't get closed. Some of them include:

- [Fun: What’s the Craziest Code You’ve Ever Written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526573/fun-whats-the-craziest-code-youve-ever-written)
- [What’s the coolest application you’ve ever worked on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118116/whats-the-coolest-application-youve-ever-worked-on)
- [What Is the most beautiful code you have ever seen or written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264/what-is-the-most-beautiful-code-you-have-ever-seen-or-written)

They were communitiy wikis, and tagged as subjective. So was mine.

Seriously, I'm not ranting (though I'm not happy about it), I just would like to understand why it got closed (as none of who voted to close left a comment). Thank you.

Comment: Some great candidates to yo-yo questions you have there.

Comment: I was able to close two of those. Thanks for bringing them to our attention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are following the logical fallacy that just because another question happened to make it through the meat grinders of community moderation that your post is therefore somehow valid.

People need to realize that questions need to be judged on their own merits, not on a comparison to the other questions.

Answer (score 5):

CW is not carte blanche to post any old garbage. None of your questions listed there (imho) have any value so I'm really not surprised.

Comment: I don't understand why you were so offensive, I just wanted an answer. I got it, learned my lesson. Have a nice day!

Comment: IMHO "garbage" isn't all that offensive. If you want to have a discussion then there are plenty of places you can do that. I for one want to see such "fluff" (if you prefer) pollute the site as little as possible. Plus, like I said, CW isn't free license to post absolutely anything.

Answer (score 1):

The other questions you cite have 2, 2, and 1 close votes respectively (at the moment).  It wouldn't surprise me if they get closed at some point..

(at which point other people may start voting to reopen because they've also got a lot of answers :-/ )